# Is there a way to remove duplicates but add the value if it appears at least once in the n selected columns?

Tags: r, summarize

For example imagine there is a dataset that looks like this

Edit:Added Date and Num column for extra context

```
ID|Date  |Col1|Col2|Col3|Num
 1  10-10  Y             5    
 1  10-10  Y    Y        5 
 1  10-10            Y   5
 2  09-17  Y             6
 2  09-17            Y   6
 3  12-14       Y        7
 3  12-14  Y             7 
 4  06-06  Y             8
 4  06-06
```

Is there a way to have an output that looks like this?

```
ID|Date  |Col1|Col2|Col3|Num
 1  10-10  Y    Y    Y   5    
 2  09-17  Y         Y   6
 3  12-14  Y    Y        7
 4  06-06  Y             8
```

```
structure(list(ID = c("000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", 
"000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000001", "000002", 
"000002", "000002", "000003", "000003", "000003", "000003", "000003", 
"000003", "000003"), Date = structure(c(1570492800, 1570492800, 
1570492800, 1570492800, 1570492800, 1570492800, 1570492800, 1570492800, 
1570492800, 1570492800, 1570665600, 1570665600, 1570665600, 1570838400, 
1570838400, 1570838400, 1570838400, 1570838400, 1570838400, 1570838400
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Col1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Col2 = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Y", "Y", "Y"), 
    Col3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, "Y", "Y", "Y"), Num1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 861, 861, 861, 497, 497, 497, 497, 497, 
    497, 497)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by 'ID', 'Date' and `summarise` the rest of the columns (`everything()`) by looping `across` them and extracting the first non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%  
   group_by(ID, Date) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(),  ~.x[!is.na(.x)][1]),
     .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  ID     Date                Col1  Col2  Col3   Num1
  <chr>  <dttm>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 000001 2019-10-08 00:00:00 Y     Y     <NA>      1
2 000002 2019-10-10 00:00:00 <NA>  Y     <NA>    861
3 000003 2019-10-12 00:00:00 <NA>  Y     Y       497
```

Comment: So my example didn't take into account that there are actually more columns in the data frame. I apologize for that. I basically want it to do the same as shown, but take into account the Date and Num column. I tried `summarise(across(df[,c"col1,col2,col3")]))` but I got error message saying character string is not in a standard unambigous format.

Comment: same with the new code, but don't know what date should affect anything.

Comment: it has nothing to do with date being type posixct?

Comment: Note the actual dataset I'm working in could not be shared so I created a dummy version of it that is slightly different than the example shown before. However same idea.

Comment: The dput I added is a much smaller subset of the actual dataset.

Comment: @user35131 I think it is `na_if("")` causing the problem.  If you remove it, works

Comment: @user35131 with your dput data, it is working fine though after removing the `na_if`

Answer (score 0):

A base R option with `aggregate`

```
      ID       Date Col1 Col2 Col3 Num1
1 000001 2019-10-08    Y    Y         1
2 000002 2019-10-10         Y       861
3 000003 2019-10-12         Y    Y  497
```